# Why are coloured parts of questions removed?

Tags: discussion, support

Out of curiosity, after I learnt the use of [MathJax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax) if I thought it necessary (obviously may be not for others), I used [the colour code](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/10116#10116) to mark any point of my question, but some users suggest edits or reputed users usually remove it by editing it!

Why does this happen? Is it a regulation? Or is it mandatory to not do such things for asking a good question?

Comment: Red screams “Look at me!” Why did you feel that “YouTube” needed to be in red? In a *title*? In my opinion, you should be glad that a moderator removed it because your question might have gotten some downvotes for the gratuitous use of color to draw attention.

Comment: @G.smith Ahh! Good point, May be it's a reason.

Answer (score 12):

The purpose of MathJax is to make mathematical formulas easier to read, **not** to emphasize text parts of your posts. Use *italic* and **bold** formatting for that.

A similar question was asked on [Chemistry Meta](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4820/157510) and I did an experiment with a screen reader. The 'nicely formatted text'

> So, in the heap of my data it looked like
>
> $$\text{Diamond in a coal mine}$$
>
> But the diamond was edited to:
> Diamond in a coal mine

led to the following being <s>read</s> heard by a visually impaired user who wants to read it:

> So, in the heap of my data it looked like
> *Diamond in a coal mine
>
> Diamond in a coal mine text
>
> Diamond in a coal mine*
> But the diamond was edited to:
> Diamond in a coal mine

That single 'nicely formatted' sentence would be heard **three times** (with a random word 'text' in between). I guess it's even worse if you put color into the equation.

Comment: and, frankly, using colour in text is even less fair for the visually impaired than the usage of text already is. Plus, we don't have colour-braille